# IQueryable vs IEnumerable - how many DB calls?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I know how `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` work. But today while I was revisiting those topics with an example.

Below are my questions

**How many DB calls are made?**

If I'm correct there are 2 DB calls, one with the `where` clause and the other when `Take(1)` is used.

```
    public void GetEmployeesByDept(long deptId)
    {
        IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq == deptId);

        // First DB call
        var firstEmployee = empDetails.Take(1);

        // Second DB call
        Console.WriteLine(empDetails.GetType());
    }
```

This is my explanation - but when I hovered over the `empDetails`, I could see the expression contains two arguments

1. `With the table`
2. `$x.Idseq == .Constant<TestProject.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2_0>(TestProject.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).deptId`

So,now when the execution finished the `firstEmployee`, I hovered over the `firstEmployee` variable, I could see the expression as below

Is this a DB call as well?

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Take(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Constant<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Employee.Models.EmployeeDetails]>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Employee.Models.EmployeeDetails]),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Employee.Models.EmployeeDetails,System.Boolean]>)),
    1).Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Employee.Models.EmployeeDetails,System.Boolean]>(Employee.Models.EmployeeDetails $x)
    {
        $x.Idseq == .Constant<TestProject.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2_0>(TestProject.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).deptId
    }
```

If this is the only DB call made among the two, then how come I am able to load the data for empDetails?

**Question #2**: now, I changed the type from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`.

My understanding here is DB call is made with `where` clause and then loads the data in-memory and then takes the first element.

Is that true?

```
public void GetEmployeesByDept(long deptId)
{
    IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq == deptId);
    // First DB call

    var firstEmployee = empDetails.Take(1); // in-memory object
    Console.WriteLine(empDetails.GetType());
}
```

Could anyone please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Query execution documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)

> **After a LINQ query is created by a user**, it is converted to a command tree. A command tree is a representation of a query that is compatible with the Entity Framework. The command tree is then executed against the data source. At query execution time, all query expressions (that is, all components of the query) are evaluated, including those expressions that are used in result materialization.

**After a LINQ query is created by a user**

You are creating the query in the lines below

```
    IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq == deptId);
    // first DB call

    var firstEmployee = empDetails.Take(1);
```

> LINQ queries are always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created.

So only one call is made, when you access the firstEmployee variable.

### Second part explanation

[IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.8) is also IEnumerable. So this line:

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq ==deptId);
```

Is not casting to IEnumerable. The `empDetails` remains `IQueryable` and will be executed again, when you access the `firstEmployee` variable.

Is is optimised by executing the query, only when it is needed.

Comment: I understand the course of execution. But, my question is how come I am able to see a bunch of `empDetails` after executing `IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq == deptId);` this line ?

Comment: Do you see any actual values?

Comment: Yes. I can see an enumerable after execution `IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails = _context.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.Idseq == deptId);`.